# Custom default notification center settings for app

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, notificationcenter

Is it possible to have custom default notification center settings for my iOS app?

The idea is that I want to allow push notifications, but do not wish to have the notifications display on the lock screen by default. All other settings are fine as is and I do not wish to hide anything.